# how to plot estimates through model in R

Tags: r, plot, modeling

I'm trying to use R to do some modelling, I've started to use BodyWeight library, since I've seen some examples online. Just to understand and get used to the commands.

I've come to my final model, with estimates and I was wondering how to plot these estimates, but I haven't seen anything online..

[image]

Is there a way to plot the values of the estimates with a line, and dots for the values of each observation?

Where can I find information about how to do this, do I have to extract the values myself or it is possible to say plot the estimates of these model?

I'm only starting with R. Any help is welcome.

Thank you

Comment: Where is the `BodyWeight` package?  I can't find it on CRAN or bioconductor.  It would be nice if you provided the code to recreate your model.

Comment: Also, while I'm being picky: a *library* is the folder that you install *packages* into.  Type `.libPaths()` to see the locations on your system.  Don't worry, everyone gets confused about this.

Comment: sorry, it is library(nlme). BodyWeight package then, inside the library nlme. Thank you :)

Comment: `BodyWeight` *dataset* inside  the `nlme` *package*. :)

Comment: dataset! ok, library is only the folder then. It's just because I've seen so many times library. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no function that just plots the output of a model, since there are usually many different possible ways of plotting the output.

Take a look at the `predict` function for whatever model type you are using (for example, linear regressions using `lm` have a `predict.lm` function).

Then choose a plotting system (you will likely want different panels for different levels of diet, so use either ggplot2 or lattice).  Then see if you can describe more clearly in words how you want the plot to look.  Then update your question if you get stuck.

---

Now we've identified which dataset you are using, here's a possible plot:

```
#Run your model
model <- lme(weight ~ Time + Diet, BodyWeight, ~ 1 | Rat)
summary(model)

#Predict the values
#predict.lme is a pain because you have to specify which rat
#you are interested in, but we don't want that
#manually predicting things instead
times <- seq.int(0, 65, 0.1)
mcf <- model$coefficients$fixed
predicted <- 
  mcf["(Intercept)"] + 
  rep.int(mcf["Time"] * times, nlevels(BodyWeight$Diet)) + 
  rep(c(0, mcf["Diet2"], mcf["Diet3"]), each = length(times))
prediction_data <- data.frame(
  weight = predicted,
  Time   = rep.int(times, nlevels(BodyWeight$Diet)),
  Diet   = rep(levels(BodyWeight$Diet), each = length(times))
)  

#Draw the plot (using ggplot2)
(p <- ggplot(BodyWeight, aes(Time, weight, colour = Diet)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(data = prediction_data)
)
```

Comment: thank you for your help, I've just seen this function: xyplot(weight~Time,data=BodyWeight,groups=Diet,type=c("p", "r"))
similar to what I wanted. It's the first time I'm actually trying to modelling something

Comment: That's not what most people would call "modeling". It's just display of data.

Comment: @DWin: Probably calling `lme` isn't what *most* people would call modeling either.  I guess they'd go for "walking up and down a stage in underwear".

Comment: It is sometimes unclear to me whether I'm hilarious or just an arse.  I'm voting for the latter in this case.

Comment: @DWin you're right, I was just trying to understand how to work with R, with this example. To apply some of these things to my data :) thank you all!